# How do I troubleshoot the problem of workers not able to get to a workplace?

Tags: simcity-2013

I suspect that my city has workers who are unable to get to their workplace. How can I  verify which workers are having trouble and troubleshoot the specific problem?

I have unemployed low-wealth workers and unsatisfied low-wealth shoppers. (I suspect I will need to zone for commercial, but I want to solve the commuting problem before adding more buildings.)

However, it seems like many workers are unable to get to a workplace. Specifically, there are low-wealth commercial buildings that say "closed for the day" and have few or no workers. (I assume the building is closed due to insufficient workers.) Also, when I use the population data map, workplaces do not contain anywhere near the maximum number of workers for the building.

My city is fairly small and young (10,000 population, so about 1,000 worker agents), so I am confident that any traffic-related problem is fixable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the answer to the title question:

If your details screen shows unemployment (which is calculated as workers - jobs), you have city level unemployment.  That can be fixed by adding jobs anywhere in the city.

If you residential buildings are running out of money (and therefore require bulldozing), you have local unemployment.  This can also be seen (with difficulty) in the residential dataview as a low money bar.  That can be fixed by adding jobs near the affected residential buildings making it easier for workers to roundtrip to those buildings.

---

Now, your actual problem was "Closed for the day".  Here's three pictures.

[image: Closed for the day is ok]

[image: Closed for workers may be temporary]

[image: 3 workers enter and all is well]

Most commercial buildings use 2 shifts.  This building only uses 1 shift.  In this case, the store isn't open at night.  During the off-shift period, you'll see the first message (in green) about being closed for the day.  This is normal and fine.  As soon as the store opens, the message will change to the red one about needing workers.  If enough workers show up (3 for LW LD C), then the message will convert to a normal business message.

1 shift buildings come in 2 varieties - day only, night only.  The number of workers in a shift is the same, regardless of the number of shifts, so a 1 shift building has half the jobs of a 2 shift building.  If you don't like single shift buildings, locate and bulldoze them.  A 2 shift building may be constructed there (it's random).